How to get end portal to generate outside the frame
I found a video that talks about weird things in Minecraft, and one of them was getting the end portal outside the end portal frames. I unfortunatly forgot what the video was called and how to get that end portal, looking in google gives me tutorial how to break the frame which is not what I want. Can someone please help me?

Welcome to Arqade! You mean something like this?

No something like this: [wacky portal] (https://bsd405-my.sharepoint.com/personal/s-jungja_bsd405_org/Documents/portal.png) (might need to ask for permission)

Sorry if the format is weird

Can't you just add some screenshots?

I just figured it out.

You can answer your own question then

@pinckerman Even if Jadon Jung has his answer, it is ok to give an answer this, right?

@Alex sure, OP hasn't provided one yet

The best answer I can come up with is that you should use commands to create the portal. For instance, /fill <from: x, y, z> <to: x, y, z> end portal.
I do know what you mean, though, about that glitch with the end portal. Here is a gif I found.

I am not sure how to perform this glitch myself, but you might find something in one of the many pages in the Minecraft wiki.
